# Is there a good reason for preferring reflection over reference?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reference, .net-assembly

Going over some legacy code, I ran into piece of code that was using reflection for loading some dll's that their source code was available (they were another project in the solution).

I was cracking my skull trying to figure out why it was done this way (naturally the code was not documented...).

My question is, can you think about any good reason for preferring to load an assembly via reflection rather than referencing it?

Comment: Plugin architecture like MEF ?

Comment: @omribitan I would say it hardly loose coupling. this might trick the IDE to believe the is loose coupling, but when you load the assembly you still need to know what it contains (e.g. method name).

Comment: @AviTurner not necessarily, it really depends on the implementation .. you could load a dll and iterate its types to look for a type implementing a certain interface for example ... any just an idea ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have a dynamic module system, where different DLLs should be loaded depending on conditions at runtime. We do this where I work; we do a license check for different optional modules that may be loaded into our system, and then only load the DLLs associated with each module if the license checks out. This prevents code that should never be executed from being loaded, which can both improve performance slightly and prevent bugs.

Dynamically loading DLLs may also allow you to drastically change functionality without changing any source code. The main assembly may for instance set in motion a discovery process where it finds all classes that implement some interface, and chooses which one to use depending on some runtime criterion.

These days you'll typically want to use [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) for this kind of task, but that's only been around since .NET 4.0, so there are probably many codebases out there that do it manually. (I don't know much about MEF. Maybe you have to do this part manually there as well.)

But anyway, the answer to your question is that there certainly are good reasons to dynamically load DLLs using reflection. Whether it applies in your case is impossible to say without more details.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing you specific project, noone here can tell you why it was done that way in your case.

But the general reasons are:

- updateability: You can simply recompile and replace the updated libary instead of having to recompile and replace the whole application.
- cooperation: if the interface is clear, that way multiple teams can work together. one for the main application and others for the dlls
- reusability: sometimes you need the same functionality in multiple projects, so the same dll can be used again and again
- extensability: in some cases you want to be able to later extend your program with plugins that where not present at shipment time. This can be realized using dlls.

I hope this helps you understand some of your setup..

Comment: While your first and last points definitely makes sense, can't you achieve `cooperation` and `reusability` using referencing and interfaces?

Comment: @AviTurner: The advantage of dlls is, that you can import libraries written in other languages like C++. It requires some effort, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
Reason for loading an assembly via reflection rather than referencing it?
```

Let us consider a scenario, where there are three classes with method `DoWork()` this method returns `string`, you  are accessing it by checking the condition (strong type).

Now you have two more classes in two different DLL's how would you cope up the change?

1)You can add `reference` of new DLL's , change the conditional check and make it work.

2)You can use `reflection` , pass on condition and assembly name at run time, this allows you to add any number of functionality at runttime without any change of code in primary appliation.